# Codeigniter ajax pagination search results not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am using the ajax pagination method from this site and made some minor changes : https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-ajax-pagination-with-search-filter/
This seems to work fine until I tried to use the pagination after searching.

Eg. When I search for something, the pagination links show up correctly, however when I click to the next page, it resets to the default pagination. Am I missing something? I have been looking and comparing for a whole day and can't seem to find what the problem is. I'm hoping someone can take a look at this for me and see if I have missed something.

This is the ajax pagination library

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax_pagination{

    var $base_url        = '';
    var $total_rows      = '';
    var $per_page        = 10;
    var $num_links       =  2;
    var $cur_page        =  0;
    var $first_link      = 'First';
    var $next_link       = '&#187;';
    var $prev_link       = '&#171;';
    var $last_link       = 'Last';
    var $uri_segment     = 3;
    var $full_tag_open   = '<ul class="pagination">';
    var $full_tag_close  = '</ul>';
    var $first_tag_open  = '<li>';
    var $first_tag_close = '</li>';
    var $last_tag_open   = '<li>';
    var $last_tag_close  = '<li>';
    var $cur_tag_open    = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    var $cur_tag_close   = '</a></li>';
    var $next_tag_open   = '<li>';
    var $next_tag_close  = '</li>';
    var $prev_tag_open   = '<li>';
    var $prev_tag_close  = '</li>';
    var $num_tag_open    = '<li>';
    var $num_tag_close   = '</li>';
    var $target          = '';
    var $anchor_class    = '';
    var $show_count      = false;
    var $link_func       = 'getData';
    var $loading         = '.loading';

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @access    public
     * @param    array    initialization parameters
     */
    function CI_Pagination($params = array()){
        if (count($params) > 0){
            $this->initialize($params);        
        }
        log_message('debug', "Pagination Class Initialized");
    }

    /**
     * Initialize Preferences
     * @access    public
     * @param    array    initialization parameters
     * @return    void
     */
    function initialize($params = array()){
        if (count($params) > 0){
            foreach ($params as $key => $val){
                if (isset($this->$key)){
                    $this->$key = $val;
                }
            }        
        }

        // Apply class tag using anchor_class variable, if set.
        if ($this->anchor_class != ''){
            $this->anchor_class = 'class="' . $this->anchor_class . '" ';
        }
    }

    function getCurrPage(){
        return $this->cur_page;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the pagination links
     * @access    public
     * @return    string
     */    
    function create_links(){
        // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
        if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0){
           return '';
        }

        // Calculate the total number of pages
        $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

        // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
        if ($num_pages == 1){
//            $info = 'Showing : ' . $this->total_rows;
            $info = '';
            return $info;
        }

        // Determine the current page number.        
        $CI =& get_instance();    
        if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0){
            $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);   
            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }

        $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;
        if ($this->num_links < 1){
            show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
        }

        if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page)){
            $this->cur_page = 0;
        }

        // Is the page number beyond the result range?
        // If so we show the last page
        if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows){
            $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
        }

        $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
        $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

        // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
        // which number to start and end the digit links with
        $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
        $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

        // Add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
        $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';

        // And here we go...
        $output = '';

        // SHOWING LINKS
        if ($this->show_count){
            $curr_offset = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);
            $info = 'Showing ' . ( $curr_offset + 1 ) . ' to ' ;

            if( ( $curr_offset + $this->per_page ) < ( $this->total_rows -1 ) )
            $info .= $curr_offset + $this->per_page;
            else
            $info .= $this->total_rows;

            $info .= ' of ' . $this->total_rows . ' | ';
            $output .= $info;
        }

        // Render the "First" link
        if  ($this->cur_page > $this->num_links){
            $output .= $this->first_tag_open 
                    . $this->getAJAXlink( '' , $this->first_link)
                    . $this->first_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "previous" link
        if  ($this->cur_page != 1){
            $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
            if ($i == 0) $i = '';
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open 
                    . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->prev_link )
                    . $this->prev_tag_close;
        }

        // Write the digit links
        for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++){
            $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;    
            if ($i >= 0){
                if ($this->cur_page == $loop){
                    $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
                }else{
                    $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open
                        . $this->getAJAXlink( $n, $loop )
                        . $this->num_tag_close;
                }
            }
        }

        // Render the "next" link
        if ($this->cur_page < $num_pages){
            $output .= $this->next_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( $this->cur_page * $this->per_page , $this->next_link )
                . $this->next_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "Last" link
        if (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages){
            $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
            $output .= $this->last_tag_open . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->last_link ) . $this->last_tag_close;
        }

        // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
        // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
        $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

        // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
        $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;
        ?>
        <script>
        function getData(page){  
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('/Common/Check'); ?>",
                success: function(data){
                    if(data==true){
                        console.log(page);
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "POST",
                            url: "<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>"+page,
                            data: { page: page },
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').show();
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log("<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>"+page);
                                $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').hide();
                                $('<?php echo $this->target; ?>').html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        window.location.href="<?php echo site_url('/');?>";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
        <?php
        return $output;
    }

        function getAJAXlink($count, $text) {
    $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
    return '<a href="javascript:void(0);"' . $this->anchor_class . ' data-per-
    page="'.$this->per_page.'" onclick="'.$this->link_func.'('.$pageCount.')">'. 
    $text .'</a>';
}
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $conditions = array();
        $data = array();
        $totalRec = count($this->ActivitiesModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions));
        $config['target']      = '#list';
        $config['base_url']    = site_url('/AdminActivities/Search');
        $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page']    = $this->get_per_page();
        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();
        $data['datatable'] = $this->ActivitiesModel->admin_get_and_search(array('limit'=>$this->get_per_page()));
        $data['user'] = $this->AccountModel->get_person($this->get_person_id());

        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/header');
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/navigation');
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/title');
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/errors');
        $this->load->view('admins/activities/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/footer');
    }

    public function search(){
        $conditions = array();
        $page = $this->input->post('page');
        if(!$page){
            $offset = 0;
        }else{
            $offset = $page;
        }
        $keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');
        if(!empty($keywords)){
            $conditions['search']['keywords'] = $keywords;
        }
        $totalRec = count($this->ActivitiesModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions));
        $config['target']      = '#list';
        $config['base_url']    = site_url('/AdminActivities/Search');
        $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page']    = $this->get_per_page();
        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
        $conditions['start'] = $offset;
        $conditions['limit'] = $this->get_per_page();
        $data['links'] = $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();
        $data['datatable'] = $this->ActivitiesModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions);
        $this->load->view('admins/activities/ajax_pagination', $data, false);
    }
```

View

```
<script>

    function searchFilter() {
    // get current page number
    var page_num = parseInt($('li.active a').text()) - 1;
    // get active li parent element to get Data-Per-Page value
    var active_parent = $('li.active a').parent('li');
    console.log('page_num: ' + page_num);
    var item_per_page = parseInt(active_parent.prev('li').find('a').data('per-page'));
    // if NaN then use Next element
    if (isNaN(item_per_page)) {
        item_per_page = parseInt(active_parent.next('li').find('a').data('per-page'));
    }
    console.log('item_per_page: ' + item_per_page);
    // Query string Keyword
    var keywords = $('#search').val();
    console.log('keywords: ' + keywords);
    // Calculate the Offset
    var page = (page_num * item_per_page);
    console.log('page: ' + page);
    // attach custom payload to ajax post
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {
            'page': page_num,
            keywords: keywords
        },
    });
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/Common/Check'); ?>",
        success: function(data){
            if(data==true){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('/AdminDocuments/Search/'); ?>'+page_num,
                    data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('.loading').show();
                    },
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#list').html(html);
                        $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
                    }
                });
            }else{
                window.location.href="<?php echo site_url('AdminLogin');?>";
            }
        }
    });
    // Use same function to build filter output with pagination
    getData(page);
}        
</script>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div class="row col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="searchFilter()"> 
    </div>
    <div id="list" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        if(!empty($datatable)){
                            foreach ($datatable as $data){
                    ?>
                        <tr class="text-left">
                            <td><?php echo $data['action']; ?> onto the <?php echo $data['page']; ?> Page on <?php echo $data['created_on']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php 
                        }
                    }else{
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">You do not have any items at the moment</td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination-links pull-right">
            <?php echo $links; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/loading/loading.gif'; ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Yes!, you are missing...***

> You missing to pass '***page_num***'  in '`onkeyup="searchFilter()"`'

You are using function like function ***searchFilter(page_num) { }*** But not sending the '***page_num***'  value. Hence, it will always be '**0**' and your pagination will be reset, when you POST with AJAX..

Another approach is use Same `getData(page)` function written in `Ajax_pagination` library class. Before do this change a little bit code inside Class:

***Update Ajax_pagination > getAJAXlink method:***

```
function getAJAXlink($count, $text) {
  $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
  return '<a href="javascript:void(0);"' . $this->anchor_class . ' data-per-
  page="'.$this->per_page.'" onclick="'.$this->link_func.'('.$pageCount.')">'. 
  $text .'</a>';
}
```

***JavaScript:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchFilter() {
    // get current page number
    var page_num = parseInt($('li.active a').text()) - 1;
    // get active li parent element to get Data-Per-Page value
    var active_parent = $('li.active a').parent('li');
    // get per page count
    var item_per_page = parseInt(active_parent.prev('li').find('a').data('per-page'));
    // if NaN then use Next element
    if (isNaN(item_per_page)) {
        item_per_page = parseInt(active_parent.next('li').find('a').data('per-page'));
    }
    // Query string Keyword
    var keywords = $('#search').val();
    // Calculate the Offset
    var page = (page_num * item_per_page);
    // attach custom payload to ajax post
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {
            'page': page_num,
            keywords: keywords
        },
    });
    // No Need to your Ajax Code Here, The getData already gives you filtered data
    // and will set in #list, basically getData posting Common/Check url and getting data
    // Here is getData post request analysis report.... :)    
    // Use same function to build filter output with pagination
    getData(page);
}
</script>
```

***Understand Flow of getData Ajax Request inside Ajax_pagination Class***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getData(page) {
    // ajax start
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        // sending request to Common/Check Controller/method
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/Common/Check'); ?>",
        success: function(data) {
            // if response returns
            if (data) {
                console.log(page);
                // call another ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    // sending request to Class Ajax_pagination Config base_url link
                    url: "<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>" + page,
                    // sending payloads page e.g. 10, 20, 30...
                    data: {
                        page: page
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').show();
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        // if response returns
                        console.log("<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>" + page);
                        $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').hide();
                        // set response inside Ajax_pagination Config target element e.g #list
                        $('<?php echo $this->target; ?>').html(data);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('/');?>";
            }
        }
    });
}            
</script>
```

***A Good Way would be, Use CodeIgniter Builtin Pagination Class. It's very easy & you can find lots of example code by just Googling.***

Then you can combined your ***Controller, Model & Views to Create Ajax Response***, After all it's just matter to return a *table html row with data* or *to return some div fancy stuff content*. The logic is behind you can call simple ajax to build your content by using ***CodeIgniter Pagination Class inside your Controller and can get data by your Model by passing limit & Offset that's it!***

**Source & Docs: [CodeIgniter Pagination Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html)**

@JianYA, Please always check ***Browser Network Panel*** to see what response we are getting while using Ajax.. it might clear more doubts instead of assumptions. You are using '***Common/Check***' inside `getData function`, So here is some question for you:

1. Do you have Common Controller & Check method?
2. Do you set `$route['Common/Check'] = 'YourController/YourMethod';` in
   `routes.php` inside `config folder` if you don't have this Controller?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for answering! Do I remove my previous searchFilter function? So far when i implement your search filter the loading page just loads and the console shows my url/Search/NaN not found.

Comment: Currently I am unable to get the page number from the getData in the ajax pagination library to my searchFilter in my index.php. Are you able to help with any suggestions?

Comment: @JianYA, did you updated Ajax_pagination > getAJAXlink method? What error you getting in Browser Console...? Do you able to get response by just simple calling Controller/Method from browser...? because i checked your code and it's fully working for me as expected.. after some modification ..

Comment: Yup! I updated it. I get the url/Search/NaN 404 error. My loading gif doesnt disappear.

Comment: I have a common controller route setup so that area is fine

Comment: I have edited my quesiton to show how I have added your code in. Can you check to see if its correct?

Comment: @JianYA, I am updating javascript  code in my answer.. let me know if it works..if you want more help please share Full Code of Controller, Model,Views and MySQL table data.. to help you better..

Comment: I have discovered that var page_num = parseInt($('li.active a').text()) - 1; keeps giving me NaN for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147525/discussion-between-neeraj-singh-and-jianya).

Answer (score 1):

hi guys without linking of database and using of ajax for autosearch with pagination here is the link and code to autosearch with pagination .i hope this help you.

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   


 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body style="margin:20px auto">  
<div class="container">

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><div class="noCrsr">Name</div></th>
            <th><div class="noCrsr">Position</div></th>
            <th><div class="noCrsr">Office</div></th>
            <th><div class="noCrsr">Age</div></th>
            <th><div class="noCrsr">Start date</div></th>
            <th><div class="noCrsr">Salary</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
  </div>
</body>  

</html>  


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
} );
  </script>
```

in the place of  table data you have used to get the php values from database so it filter the search of only in table data itself.

Comment: Hey Iswarya, Please provide answer related to the question.

Comment: hi @RohitDhiman you can see the answer now in my post i was edited now

Comment: Great, I can see you have suggested another method of solving the above question, please try to solve the problem itself first as @neerajsingh did. Although we appreciate your efforts.

Comment: yeah sure @RohitDhiman if these method  is useful means upvote for me yar